# What are the consequences of changing the email linked to my ssh public key?

Tags: git, email, github, ssh

I currently have one public/private pair of ssh keys that I mainly used for my college coursework. Since I linked my university email to the key upon creation, I would like to update it to my personal email for future projects.

As [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563677/best-practice-for-using-ssh-key-pair-with-different-groups) notes, the email is simply a comment used to identify the key and does not affect commit attributions.

If I modify my file directly in, ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, how will this affect its appearance on sites like GitHub and GitLab?
For example, [here are my GitHub SSH settings with my old email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J79uw.png).

Would I have to delete this key and reenter it in order for the email to update in the title? Or is the original email hardcoded into the key? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would I have to delete this key and reenter it in order for the email to update in the title?

Yes.

> Or is the original email hardcoded into the key?

No, it is not part of the public key, which would remain the same.
Ie, GitHub would still recognize that public key even if you change the last part in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Deleting and registering that *same* public ssh key is not mandatory here:
its associated email is just for you to remember what that key stands for.
But the key itself would still work with its old email registration.

Answer (score 11):

If you're talking about the text to the right of the SSH key, then this is a comment.  It's just a label for anybody reading the file, it doesn't do anything.  You can change it to anything you'd like or delete it.